# Setting up Ubuntu Server on Amazon EC2 for hosting multiple domains with wildcard subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, web-hosting, virtualhost

I'm trying to set up multiple domains on my Amazon EC2 micro instance running Ubuntu Server 12.04. I installed Apache correctly and set up virtual hosts but having problems with wildcard subdomains.

This is what my httpd.conf file looks like

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/username/domains/%0/html/
</VirtualHost>
```

My DNS records (on Amazon Route 53) are:

```
domain.tld      A    1.2.3.4
*.domain.tld    A    1.2.3.4
```

If i create a `test.domain.tld` directory with the `html` subdirectory, it works fine. But what I want to do is to redirect `*.domain.tld` to `domain.tld` in case there is no directory for the sub-domain accessed. I would also like `www.domain.tld` to redirect to `domain.tld`. The system should also work if I decide to host another website, `example.com`, on the server.

I tried Googling a lot but without any luck. Suggestions?

Comment: This is all apache, sites-available, and .htaccess related. Have you considered using nginx? Some people say it is easier to set up.

Comment: No but I want to use Apache. It's used by practically every web hosting company out there so there has to be some way to do this

Comment: Yes, and people still have telephones with push bottons that plug into a wall! Your question is google-able and just takes some work on a webserver. I have set up 3 or 4 apache servers; trial and error answered my problems like this. Oh, read this: http://www.ichilton.co.uk/blog/web/nginx-and-why-you-should-be-running-it-instead-of-or-at-least-in-front-of-apache-380.html

Comment: I have a rotary phone sitting on my desk, too. It doesn't dial out on my VoIP line. Such is the nature of progress. Web hosting companies only use Apache because it's what their billing and provisioning software supports (though some are starting to switch to nginx).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to check whether the document root exists, and send a redirect if it doesn't.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} ! -d
RewriteRule .* http://domain.tld/ [R]
```